# Save terminal tabs to saved workspace VSCode

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to save Terminal settings to a workspace? For most of my projects I always have two terminal tabs open. One where I do all of my git work and one where I run gulp tasks. These are two different folders and neither are the project root. When I open a saved workspace it always just opens one tab to the project root.

Comment: Won't meet all of your requirements, but be sure to check out the `terminal.integrated.cwd` setting. Use it to create a custom "current working directory" and add it to your workspace settings.

Answer (score 26):

Look at the [Restore Terminals](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EthanSK.restore-terminals) extension.  For example, in your settings.json:

```
 "restoreTerminals.runOnStartup": false,   // true is the default
          // set to false if using a keybinding or command palette

  "restoreTerminals.terminals": [
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "git",
          "commands": [
            "cd <your directory>",
            "npm run test"         // your git command(s)
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "gulp",
          "commands": [
            "cd zip",
            "gulp sass"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

will open two terminals, one for your `git` work and one for the `gulp` work.  They can each take multiple commands.

Example keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+t",    // whatever keybinding if you wish
  "command": "restore-terminals.restoreTerminals",
},
```

or you can it run at start-up.

Comment: wow this is pretty cool i wonder who made it

Answer (score 12):

The **Tasks feature** is the current recommended way to handle this. There is no need for an extension. See [Automating launching of terminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_automating-terminals-with-tasks) in the VS Code documentation.

Then make sure that tasks are run automatically when the folder is opened by running command **Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder** and choosing **Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder** (see [Run behavior](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_run-behavior)).

Please also see the note [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) that:

> Task support is only available when working on a workspace folder. It is not available when editing single files."

You can set arbitrary commands to run in the terminal sessions automatically on startup. If however you just want terminals to stay open, set the command key to your shell. Here's an example:

```json
{
    "label": "myterminal",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "/bin/zsh",
    "args": ["-l"],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/mysubdirectory"
    },
    "isBackground": true,
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "presentation": {
        "group": "mygroup"
    }
},
```

Comment: this does not work when i close vs code and start it over

Comment: Updated the answer with information on how to allow automatic tasks in folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: @WeltFahr Do you know how to prevent VSCode from closing these terminals and leaving them to work in?

Comment: @virtual98 The terminals remain open as long as you keep VSCode open. Are you asking whether they can be left open when VSCode is closed? Just to make sure I understand you question. The latter would not be possible.

Comment: I've been looking at this for 15 minutes and still don't know what to do. I think that's the need for an extension.

Comment: @xr280xr: you have to follow the linked documentation, that is creating a `.vscode/tasks.json` file with your configuration and running the **Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder** command as stated above. Where are you stuck in this process?

Comment: This anwser does not fit for people who want persistant terminal tabs. The terminals that open are special "task terminals" and close upon finished execution of their commands.
My case was that I wanted 3 terminals open upon start: 1 for yarn start(dev web server), 1 that executes a second server we depend on, and the third for various other commands I might need. While the first two execute, the third one closes upon key press because its "task" finished. 

For actual terminals, we need an extension

Comment: @ThatBrianDude: I have added an example on how to set a shell as a task, which will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 10):

I use this User setting:

[image: Restoring terminal session in VSCode]

It has the nice benefit of working across all directories/projects and of not requiring to save anything to any particular project.

Comment: thanks! it remembers my terminals layout, even though it didn't remember the working directory of each of the terminals,
any way to persist the working directory ?

Comment: As of December 2023 I don't see this recalling my terminal layout or working directory. It doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

For a Linux not-so-officially-recommended way that works. The xdotool key emulator for linux can be used. I'm sure any Windows key emulator could be used to accomplish the same thing.

First, set the `Terminal: Change Color` to a keyboard shortcut. Here I'm using Ctrl+Shift+C. This is done by bringing up the command pallet (Cntrl+Shift+P) and, typing `Terminal: Change Color`

[image]

Here is my Restore Terminals json from VS Code settings. The lengthy cli command to update the colors needs to be activated on the last tab, as it is the tab that is focused when Restore Tabs is finished restoring tabs.
We need a bit of a timeout between the setting of each tab color, as VS Code takes just about a 10th of a second to complete the command. The built in keyboard shortcut cntrl+Page_Up is used to bring the previous tabs into focus. This script is for a WorkSpace that includes a Docker-Compose enviroment that contains 3 repos.
Be sure to save this in your Workspace settings, not your user settings. For more info, visit: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

```
      "restoreTerminals.terminals": [
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "docker-compose",
          "commands": ["cd ..", "cd docker-compose", "clear"]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "api",
          "commands": ["cd ..", "cd api", "clear"]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "ui",
          "commands": [
                "cd ..",
                "cd ui",
                "xdotool key ctrl+shift+c && xdotool type 'cyan' && xdotool key Return && sleep .2",
                "xdotool key ctrl+Page_Up && xdotool key ctrl+shift+c && xdotool type 'green' && xdotool key Return && sleep .2",
                "xdotool key ctrl+Page_Up && xdotool key ctrl+shift+c && xdotool type 'yellow' && xdotool key Return",
                "clear"
            ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
```

And the end result... Is that all tab colors are updated after they are restored.
Of course, anyone who has ever used keyboard emulation for automating tasks should know you can not be entering text or clicking elsewhere until the task is complete.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Restore Terminals extension. Just need to setting up in settings.json two options:

```
"restoreTerminals.runOnStartup": true,
"restoreTerminals.keepExistingTerminalsOpen": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows you can use powershell to create a similar effect to @CodeBloodedChris's solution.

Create a powershell script in your workspace root directory (or where ever the last terminal's final path is) and name it something like 'restore-terminal-customization.ps1' or something like that. Then add the following code to it:

```
# Uses windows forms to send keystrokes to customize vscode Terminals
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$tabDelay = .6

# Last Terminal 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^+cRed~")

# Second to last Terminal
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{PGUP}"); Start-Sleep -s $tabDelay
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^+cYellow~")

# Third to last Terminal
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{PGUP}"); Start-Sleep -s $tabDelay
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^+cMagenta~")
```

In this script the '^+c' is ctrl+shift+c and '~' is the enter key.
Similarly I had also set up a keybinding for the icons which uses ctrl+shift+i '^+i'. Here's an example of setting both the color and the icon of a terminal:

```
# Fourth to last Terminal
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{PGUP}"); Start-Sleep -s $tabDelay
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^+cGreen~^+iorganization~")
```

In your restoreTerminal's config call the script you created as a command in the last terminal on your list.

```
"restoreTerminals.terminals": [
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "docker-compose",
          "commands": ["cd ..", "cd docker-compose", "clear"]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "api",
          "commands": ["cd ..", "cd api", "clear"]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "ui",
          "commands": [
                "cd ..",
                "cd ui",
                ".\restore-terminal-customization.ps1",
                "clear"
            ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Don't forget to set the keybindings to the `Terminal: Change Color` and `Terminal: Change Icon` commands in VsCode.