# VSCode is there a way to save terminal setup?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to save terminal setup in VSCode, so I have several terminals I run with certain workspace and with new feature that allows to rename terminal setup a color and icon it would be quite neat to have ability to restore after shutdown.

There is following post: [Save terminal tabs to saved workspace VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312095/save-terminal-tabs-to-saved-workspace-vscode), (I could not comment there sorry as I do not have more than 50 points.)
That post is suggesting usage of ***Restore Terminals*** extension but that one does not have ability to set tab icon and tab color.
Is there a more complete solution or native way in VS code that will allow to save/restore terminals?

Comment: As you correctly mention, this is a duplicate. I agree that for many the Restore Terminals extension is not a preferred solution. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68540643/13431526 about the recommended solution.